# Asymptotics for sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

Could you give me a hint how to find $c$ in the asymptotic for the sum:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor {n}/{2} \rfloor}\binom{n-k+1}{k}=(c+o(1))^n
$$
and for
$$
\max\limits_{a\leq n/2}\frac{\binom{n}{a}}{\sum_{k=0}^{a/2}\binom{n}{k}}=(c+o(1))^n
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT for the first problem: Note that $$F_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\lceil n/2\rceil}\binom{n+1-k}k\;,$$ where $F_n$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number. (This can be proved without too much trouble by induction on $n$.) Thus,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n-k+1}k=\begin{cases}
F_{n+1},&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
F_{n+1}-\binom{(n+1)/2}{(n+1)/2}=F_{n+1}-1,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;.
\end{cases}$$

You probably already know something about the asymptotics of the Fibonacci numbers.

For the second question see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/548218/12042).

Comment: Thanks.
Are there any common way to solve such kind of problems? Any good reading?

Comment: @WickedSpirit: I’m not really the one to ask, I’m afraid: I’ve done very little along these lines. I just happened to recognize the first sequence as being very close to a standard identity involving binomial coefficients and Fibonacci numbers. By the way, I don’t know whether it will help, but the denominator in the other one simplifies to $\binom{n+1}{(a/2)+1}$ by another standard identity.